# Result of single bit bitwise vs logical inversion is interpreted differently in arithmetic expression

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Consider the following code:

```
module test;
  reg signed [3:0] signed_reg3 = 4;
  reg ubit = 0;
  
  initial begin
    $display("! => typename: %s, size: %d, %d", $typename(!ubit), $bits(!ubit), signed_reg3 - !ubit);
    $display("~ => typename: %s, size: %d, %d", $typename(~ubit), $bits(~ubit), signed_reg3 - ~ubit );
  end
endmodule
```

The result in the simulator of the two prints is:

```
 ! => typename: reg, size:           1,  3
 ~ => typename: reg, size:           1,  5
```

(Here is the [Demo](https://edaplayground.com/x/JH3x) )
As we can see, there is a difference in the result of evaluation of the following two arithmetic expressions:

```
signed_reg3 - !ubit
signed_reg3 - ~ubit
```

In the first case the `!ubit` result is interpreted as unsigned value, while in the second, `~ubit` seem to be interpreted as signed. This is something I do not understand, as the same print is showing that both type and size of either result is the same (`reg` of size `1` bit).
Please explain what is happening here.

Comment: See the "Verilog Expressions" section of https://dvcon-proceedings.org/document/systemverilog-constraints-appreciating-what-you-forgot-in-school-to-get-better-results/

Comment: @dave_59 Thanks for the edit...no idea how these zeros got there.. pretty sure I just copy-pasted from the simulator (removing the line headings..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are displaying the result of `$bits` in a different context from when used within an arithmetic expression.

Table 11-21 shows the logical-not `!` returning a 1-bit result and its operand is self-determined. Whereas the bitwise-not `~` returns a bit width of its context determined operand. The fact that `!` always returns a 1-bit value is something that was [further clarified](https://accellera.mantishub.io/view.php?id=1975) in the next revision of the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595).

Section *11.8.2 Steps for evaluating an expression* explains how the bit-widths get propagated through context determined expressions.

To summarize

```
signed_reg3 - !ubit
```

The logical negation applies to the 1-bit value `ubit` *before* it gets extended to 4-bits because its operand is self-determined.

```
signed_reg3 - ~ubit
```

Since `~ubit` is part of the context of the subtraction operator, its operand gets extended *before* bitwise-negation and subtraction.

Comment: Thanks for the missing bit about `!` being self-determined. I was looking in the 1364-2005 revision and this piece wasn't there.

Comment: Table 5-22 in the 1364-2005 LRM and Table 29 in the 1364-2001 LRM

Comment: Riiight... how I missed it? Not a first my mistake today, probably shouldn't do anything important today...

Answer (score 1):

These 2 expressions are evaluated as 4-bit expressions:

```
signed_reg3 - !ubit
signed_reg3 - ~ubit
```

This means that `!ubit` and `~ubit` are also treated as 4-bit expressions where `ubit` is expanded from 1-bit to 4-bits.  When `ubit` is 0, it is expanded to `4'b0000` **before** the other operators are applied.

`!ubit` = `!(4'b0000)` = **logical** not of 0 = 1 = `4'b0001`

`~ubit` = `~(4'b0000)` = **bitwise** not of 0 = `4'b1111`

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 11. *Operators and expressions*.

Comment: I've imagined that could be the case, but I can't find any reference or rationale for this behavior. Why is `ubit` expanded before evaluating the unary operator? Isn't `!ubit` or `~ubit` considered an "standalone" expression and should be evaluated before according to it's highest precedence?

Comment: It also looks like the `!` operator is producing a single bit value regardless of the operand size ([demo](https://edaplayground.com/x/v4CQ)), so expanding the operand before evaluating `!` will still produce 1-bit value (which might be still expanded to produce `4'b0001` in the full expression, but again it is not add much clarity..)

Answer (score 1):

Subtraction is a context determined operator.
Context determined means that all operands get modified to be the same size, and signedness using 0 extension or sign extension.

The two cases you have expand differently based on ! or ~.

See IEEE 1800 2017 section 11.6.1 "Rules for expression bit lengths" and the following sections for details and examples.

Another source of info and examples on this topic is here: [standard_gotchas_presentation](https://sutherland-hdl.com/papers/2006-SNUG-Boston_standard_gotchas_presentation.pdf)

Note the context for size and signedness are different.

Comment: Ok, this clarifies it a bit. I was missing the concept of "self-determined" vs "context-determined" expressions. I think the most relevant sentence is the one from the section 5.5.2: *Propagate the type and size of the expression (or self-determined subexpression) back down to the
context-determined operands of the expression. In general, **any context-determined operand of an
operator shall be the same type and size as the result of the operator...***

Comment: So basically, we first determine that the size of the result of the full expression is 4 bit, then we determine that the size of the subexpression result of `~ubit` should be 4 bit, and since it is context-determined expression, it's operand should be of the same size as it's result, so `ubit` is expanded into 4 bits.

Comment: Which is different from `!ubit`, as it is a self-determined operation resulting in 1-bit result, which is expanded only after the evaluation. One thing that is missing is the reference proving `!x` is self-determined.

Comment: Looks like I looked at an outdated standard. The one you are referring does provide this info